# How to add a comma between each item in foreach, @html.displayfor

Tags: c#, html

I want to add a comma after each language.Language.NativeName
Right now they all just come out in one straight line.
I cant just add a comma in the NativeName get method because i will use it for other stuff aswell.

```
<td class=" ">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
<td class=" ">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country.Name)</td>
<td class=" ">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)</td>
<td class=" ">
@foreach (UserLanguage language in item.Languages)
{
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => language.Language.NativeName)
}
</td>
<td class=" ">Danish, English, Spanish</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string.Join:

```
<td class=" ">@String.Join(", ", item.Languages.Select(p => p.Language.NativeName).ToArray())</td>
```

Comment: Yes i know, but i had to wait for 10 minutes to be able to accept it.

Comment: No problem, glad to help